# history-search-backward working differently in zsh than in bash

Tags: zsh

I have `history-search-backward` mapped as PageUp.

When I type:

```
git push <PageUp><PageUp><PageUp>
```

1. in Bash it begins to cycle through all history entries beginning with **git push**
2. in Zsh it begins to cycle through all history entries beginning with **git** so it will list entries such `git status`, `git remote update` etc. This is not what I want.

How can I have zsh behave like bash? What `setopt` should I set?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### **Bind the history search** of zsh to `[Page UP]` and `[Page Down]`

```
bindkey "^[[5~" history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey "^[[6~" history-beginning-search-forward
```

---

### **Bind the history search** of zsh to `[UP]` and `[Down]`

```
bindkey "^[[A~" history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey "^[[B~" history-beginning-search-forward
```

Comment: If you want that the same functionality but with Up and Down arror, replace the binding key `"^[[5~"` to `"^[[A"` and `"^[[6~"` to `"^[[B"`

Comment: zsh's history-beginning-search still have a subtle difference from bash(readline)'s history-search. readline's command is equivalent to history-backward/forward (and put the cursor at the end of the line) before u move the cursor in the line (which will make it turns into "history-beginning-search") while zsh's ones always put the cursor at the beginning of the line. Is there a easy way to change this behavior without writing a new widget? THX

Comment: @yuyichao, did you perhaps find how to make `zsh` behave like `bash`?

Comment: @courteous Not really, Although I'm getting used to the zsh behavior after using it for some time... Especially since a simple `<C-e>` can turn the `zsh` behavior to the `bash` behavior but not so easy the other way around.